# Add .class files path to JRuby run command line

Tags: ruby, class, compiler-construction, command, jruby

I have 2 file in folder: `~/hello.rb` and `~/help.rb`. hello.rb requires help.rb.
I have compiled them into ~/build/ folder with:

```
jrubyc -t build/ .
```

When i run hello.rb with jruby, jruby searches for help.class in ~/, but I want to tell  it to look in ~/build/ folder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but this seems to be what you're asking...

```
require 'build/help'
```

Alternatively, us the `-I` switch to include a path at run time:

```
jruby -Ibuild hello.rb
```